# Is multiple try-catch in error sensitive code considered a good practice?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a code segment that is responsible for orchestrating the execution of a few modules and it is very sensitive to errors - I want to make sure I log and alert about every exception that occurs.

Right now I have something like this:

```
try
{
    ModuleAResult aResult = ModuleA.DoSomethingA();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string errorMessage = string.Format("Module A failed doing it's thing. Specific exception: {0}", ex.Message);
    // Log exception, send alerts, etc.
}
try
{
    ModuleBResult bResult = ModuleB.DoSomethingB();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string errorMessage = string.Format("Module B failed doing it's thing. Specific exception: {0}", ex.Message);
    // Log exception, send alerts, etc.
}

// etc for other modules.
```

It looks to me that the multiple try-catch is making this segment less readable. Is it indeed the right thing to do?

Comment: _"Is it indeed the right thing to do?"_ Yes. But it depends whether you want to proceed on error with the other modules or not. If you want to stop on the first error you need nested `try-catchs`. If you want to access any of those results outside of the `try-catchs` you need to declare the variables outside.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "If you want to stop on the first error you need nested try-catchs." This statement is actually the opposite

Comment: @Leo: OP's concatenating them which means that he will proceed the others even if one of the previous already had an error. If that's not desired he need to nest the `try-catch`, so that he only proceed if `DoSomethingXY` succeeded. What's wrong with this statement?

Comment: @TimSchmelter never mentioned there was anything wrong with the statement...hit "Enter" before finishing...but, never mind

Comment: "It looks to me that the multiple try-catch is making this segment less readable." - You may be able to make it cleaner with a wrapper function that takes in a Func or Action and a string for the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did well.

This way, you can process the error after each module. If you want to run it all and then do error handling, consider this alternative:

```
try
{
    ModuleAResult aResult = ModuleA.DoSomethingA();
    ModuleBResult bResult = ModuleB.DoSomethingB();
}
catch(ModuleAException ex)
{
    // handle specific error
}
catch(ModuleBException ex)
{
    // handle other specific error
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle all other errors, do logging, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the right thing.

But you should have the performance in in mind, maybe it's better to put all method calls in one try/catch and add stack trace and error information in the exception in the methiod itself.

```
public void ModuleA.DoSomethingA()
{
    throw new Exception("Error in module A");
}

try
{
    ModuleAResult aResult = ModuleA.DoSomethingA();
    ModuleBResult bResult = ModuleB.DoSomethingB();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // get information about exception in the error message
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this approach better since/if the processing of the two catch blocks are exactly the same, the only difference seems to be the module name in the `errorMessage` variable...which serves very little purpose

Comment: @Leo: Maybe that message is just for demonstration purposes. You will never be able to differentiate between the errors with this approach and you'll get worse(more general) informations in your logs. You also cannot run different logic dependent on certain  types of  errors.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not too sure what you're point is but "my point" is that if the processing is the same, the code should be refactored to eliminate duplication...whether for demonstration or not, that's not specified in the question and seems irrelevant to me. Finally, why would you need to differentiate errors when the main purpose of error logging is persisting information about something that went wrong? Doesn't the stack trace eliminates the need to add "Module B failed..." in the error message?

Comment: The different error messages were indeed on purpose and meant to show I am creating a different error message for each module. I don't want to use the stack trace because this short error message is sent over SMS, but I still want to know where the failure occurred.

Comment: You have the stacktrace as property in the exception itself, so you can get the information where the failure occure.
Additional you can change the error message in each module and add you info here.

Answer (score 0):

i think that depends on the approach that you want to follow.

It seems like you error messsages are different for each module that raises exception so i guess the approach that you followed is right.

you could have put the whole thing in a big try - catch block then in that case you will not know which module caused the exception as a generic excpetion gets printed.

```
try
 {
    ModuleAResult aResult = ModuleA.DoSomethingA();
    ModuleBResult bResult = ModuleB.DoSomethingB();
 }
catch (Exception ex)
 {
   string errorMessage = string.Format("Either Module A or B failed", ex.Message);
// Log exception, send alerts, etc.
 }
```

So if you want your exception handling to not be cleaner use the above code.
Otherwise what you followed is absolutely fine.